# ASP.net Web Application Pages Stop Responding (Web Forms) on IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Well, we have an web application deployed on:

```
  Windows Server 2012 
  IIS 8.​
  Target .net Framework 4.0
  DevExpress Ver: 13.1.8           (third-party controls)
```

Now the issue is this, some of the pages stop responding when we try to load them. (after few time- not specific) 
To make them in working again we have to restart 'World Wide Web Publishing Service' or sometime 'IIS' as well.

But after few hours, again the pages stop responding. Browser does't even give any error message, just keep trying
to load page and go in 'Waiting for Server Response' state.

And this behavior is not for all page. Even under this scenario some other pages still work. It means application is running
but some pages are note working.

I have also check that there is no dead lock at database level.
Also, IIS 8 is enable with both 3.5 and 4.5 options.

Note: We have some other applications on the same server running fine.

Can you please suggest me that how can I resolve this issue,

Thanks

Qazi
​

Comment: check out for deadlocks and in the windows event logs.

Comment: Do you have a page where users can upload large files? The file upload process can block other IIS processes...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a Hello World! page and load it. 
If the Hello World page even doesn't load, analyse the IIS log .

especially look at the value of "Win32Status" . If its not 0, use - net helpmsg [Win32StatusCode] in command line . This should give you enough clue for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is the  HTTP Compression that is causing the issue; dump the HTTP Compression in Web Extensions, and then it will behave better.

Check also your CPU and RAM workload.